# Is is possible to have a bidirectional edge in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js, vis.js

I want to make a network graph that looks similar to this below image.

[Click on this link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0wOw.png)

I have searched across and have not found a solution for this using Cytoscape.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create bidirectional edges in Cytoscape.js. First, the curve-styles of your edges should be different than 'haystack' (below I set it as 'straight'), because 'haystack' doesn't support edge endpoint arrows. Second, you need to specify source and target endpoint arrow shapes. Possible values for arrow shapes are listed [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-arrow) (I used 'triangle-backcurve' below). If you want one directional edge, you can set the arrow shape only for source or target.

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'curve-style': 'straight',
      }
    }
  ],
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0n1',
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1n2',        
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2n3',        
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n3'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});

cy.getElementById('n0n1').style({'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve', 'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve'});
cy.getElementById('n1n2').style({'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve'});
cy.getElementById('n2n3').style({'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle-backcurve'});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.10.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```