# Can you have bidirectional edges in cytoscape charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, cytoscape.js

Can I program edges with arrows on both sides in cytoscape charts - (both toward the source node and toward the target node)?

This seems like an odd thing to want to do, but since the charts produced by cystoscape allow edges to go 'under' nodes that have been positioned in between the source and target node, having arrows on both sides of the edge tells you what two nodes the edge is really intended to connect.

So is there a way to make an edge that looks like <------> ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have a bidirectional edge in cytoscape.js. Take a look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060797/6892480